# Injecting factories into config blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not figure this one out. Currently diving into more `injection` docs, but I'm not sure *why* this doesn't work. In the example below, `myConstants.defaultPath` logs as *undefined*.

```
(function() {
  angular.module('my-constants', []).factory('myConstants', [
    function() {
      var service;
      return service = {
        defaultPath: '/aroute'
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);


(function() {
  var app, config;

  app = angular.module('my-app', ["my-constants"]);

  config = function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, myConstants) {

    console.log(myConstants.defaultPath); // undefined

    return $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: myConstants.defaultPath
    });
  };

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'myConstantsProvider'];

  app.config(config);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to register constants with `module.constant` and it will be available in both `config` and any other method.

```
angular.module('my-constants', []).constant('myConstants', {
  defaultPath: '/aroute'
})
```

Inject to config (note: `myConstants` not `myConstantsProvider`):

```
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'myConstants'];
```